# Get results based on the first letter of the field data in CakePHP

Tags: php, sql, regex, cakephp, alphabetical

I'm trying to create a page where users can search through all the records of a particular model, in my case albums. In the view I use:

```
    for ($i = 65; $i < 90; $i++) { 
        echo $html->link(chr($i), array('action' => 'letter_find', chr($i))) , ' - '; 
    }
```

to print out each letter of the alphabet followed by a '-' (can anyone tell me how not to have the '-' after the last letter?). The user clicks on a letter and is passed to the letter_find action with the appropriate letter passed as a variable.

Here's where I get stuck. I'm not completely sure how I'm meant to find all the albums beginning with the selected letter. Like I said in the title, I'm a total neub. This is probably something very simple to do?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: move your hyphen to the next line and wrap it in an if block: if($i != 89) echo " - ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it, and it will return the $results as an array:

```
$results = $this->model->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('model.field LIKE'=>$letter.'%')));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ( range( 'a', 'z' ) as $l ) {
    $links[] = $html->link($l, array('action' => 'letter_find', $l));
}

echo implode( ' - ', $links );
```

Answer (score 1):

'Model.field LIKE ' . $letter . '%' is the condition you put in your find

## EDIT

you might also like this

find available letters - https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/beta/core/libs/models/behaviors/infinitas.php#L525

show a list of available letters - https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/beta/core/filter/views/helpers/filter.php#L140